# Do coinbase transactions use stealth addresses?

Tags: stealth-address, coinbase-transaction

When miners are awarded a block reward my understanding is that it occurs using a "Coinbase transaction" do Coinbase transactions send Monero to the Miners public address directly or do they use stealth addresses? i understand they dont use RingCT and use 0 Mixin ring signatures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[moneropedia](https://getmonero.org/resources/moneropedia/stealthaddress.html)

> Stealth addresses are an important part of Monero's inherent privacy. They allow and require the sender to create random one-time addresses for **every** transaction on behalf of the recipient.